# $\operatorname{Ann}(G)=$?, where $G$ is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

As every Abelian Group $G$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. It is easy to see that if $|G|=n$, then $n\mathbb{Z} \subset \operatorname{Ann}(G)$.
Can we tell that for every group $G$, $n\mathbb{Z}=\operatorname{Ann}(G)$?

If $G=\mathbb{Z}_n$ then it is true. Is this true in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ${\rm Ann}(G)=e\mathbb{Z}$ where $e$ is the **exponent** of $G$, i.e. the lcm of the orders of the elements of $G$.

For instance
$${\rm Ann}((\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^r)=2\mathbb{Z}
$$
whatever $r$.